# SipManager.isApiSupported() and SipManager.isVoipSupported() returning false

Tags: android, voip, sip

Is there any configuration to enable VOIP on device? Or these methods really show that my device does not support VOIP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is a little late to answer, but after a lot of searching, I reached the fact that you are supposed to use any `SipStack`, because as explained [here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread114876.html):

> Fusion SIP source code is specifically designed for use in embedded
>   devices, has a small footprint and is completely ROMable and
>   re-entrant. The Fusion SIP stack provides a simplified API for easy
>   integration with the application and transport stack (TCP/IP/UDP).

and when talking about android specifically, as explained in the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782257/sip-manager-api-support):

> All Android devices, which can connect to the Internet, support SIP.
>
> After all SIP is just a protocol which requires connection to the
>   Internet, and it's very similar to HTTP.
>
> In order to work with SIP, you need SIPStack implementation - doesn't
>   matter if it's 3rd party or it comes from Android API.

and about examples of SipStacks that can be used, you will find a punch of them like [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) and [Doubango](http://www.doubango.org/), and all exists in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9787556/android-sip-stack-what-to-use).

Comment: Vaow, an answer after 4 years :) I will mark your answer and hope it helps someone else. Thank you.

Comment: @OnuraySahin thanks :) , I came across your question while searching for an answer to that issue, and when finding it, I came to it back in order to illustrating what I got from my searching :)