# Samsung galaxy S and Samsung galaxy Y support to SIP?

Tags: android, sip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sip Manager api support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9782257/sip-manager-api-support)

i try SipManager.isApiSupported(context) and SipManager.isApiSupported(context) on samsung S(2.3) and galaxy Y(2.3) but both are return false. 
it mean both devices not support sip?
How to achieve that?