# Android wear 2.0 - SIP API support

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I wrote SIP client to register my phone, and make and receive SIP calls. I am able to successfully implement it in Android phones. But the ultimate aim is, I need to implement this for Android watches using Android wear 2.0. Before flashing the watch with Android wear 2.0 image, I tested with Android wear 1.x and found that SIP Api support is not there for 1.x. As the preview image will void the watch warranty, I wanted to make sure what features can work on Android wear 2.0 before starting the implementation. When I searched for, I don't see anywhere that SIP API support is in Android Wear 2.0. Can someone confirm whether Android wear 2.0 has support for SIP or not? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that SIP API is not supported (or maybe not yet?) in Android Wear. From this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html):

> **Note**: Not all Android-powered devices support VOIP calls using SIP. You should always call [`isVoipSupported()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#isVoipSupported(android.content.Context)) to verify that the device supports VOIP calling and [`isApiSupported()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/sip/SipManager.html#isApiSupported(android.content.Context)) to verify that the device supports the SIP APIs. Your application must also request the [`INTERNET`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#INTERNET) and [`USE_SIP`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#USE_SIP) permissions.

I'm not sure with this since I don't try yet, but according to this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9965345/5832311), you can use 3rd party SIPStack implementation to make SIP supported.

You can find in this [link](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2016/05/android-wear-20-developer-preview.html) the only features that Android Wear 2.0 supports.